# hg merge on command line hangs after first file merge

Tags: mercurial, p4merge

I've configured my command line hg to use p4merge.

When I merge in a branch and there is a conflict, hg opens p4merge, to which I resolve the issues, save, then close p4 merge.

Meanwhile...

The command line is stuck on:

running merge tool p4mergeosx for file

There is no way to tell the command line that I'm finished and need to move on already. The only thing I can do is kill the whole merge, and then this cancels the whole operation, and I need to start all over again.

How do I fix this?

This happens with other mergetools too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact issue with FileMerge.

After saving the file in question, you must also **quit** FileMerge (`command q` on a Mac), rather than just closing it.

Again, this solved my problem when using FileMerge specifically - hopefully p4merge is a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to debug Mercurial commands with debug tools. Try to add this to your commands and maybe you will get some useful information

```
--debug --traceback
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Two Answers:

1. Make sure to save the file in p4merge, then exit the application from the menu. This should kick your command line to the next step.
2. Use meld instead. This is an awesome tool